# How to make all hyperlinks on pages ( Not Menus the same colour )

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

Hi i am trying to make all the hyperlinks site wide the same colour rather than having to go through hundreds of pages.

I have been trying the following but no joy.

Here is my code:

```
.yoast-link-suggestion__value a:link {color:#000000; !important;}

.yoast-link-suggestion__value a:visited {color: #000000; !important; }

.yoast-link-suggestion__value a:hover {color: #000000; !important; }

.yoast-link-suggestion__value a:active {color: #000000; !important;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
.yoast-link-suggestion__value
```

from each line. Simply use just the tag like this

```
a:hover { /* style here */ }
a:visited { /* etc etc */ }
```

Now, ALL links will take on this style.  Of course, as long as this css file is included.

Now, for your menus you can select a tags that are within your menus parent container specifically

```
.menu-container-name a:hover { /* style here */ }
.menu-container-name a:visited { /* etc etc */ }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me i tried this and no joy

Comment: a:link, a:hover {
        color: #ff0000 !important;
    }

Comment: Also these links are being attached to pages by using yoast suggested link option not sure if that's relevant or not.

thanks

Danny

Comment: Hi the issue was to do with cache i tried it on another browser and it worked. Thanks so much

Comment: if this is the correct answer you should mark it as so.